# How can i calculate such integral in maple?

Tags: function, maple, orthogonal

Beloew Hyperlink shows Orthogonal Functions.
I used different commands in maple but i can't apply these Integral expressions in Maple.
How can i integrate such conditional Integrals ??? (For Example the Integral with red box around it)

[Orthogonal Functions](http://uupload.ir/files/43hs_1237.jpg)

Comment: Please post all the relevant code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is more of a math Question than a programming Question, so it probably should've gone to math.stackexchange.com.)

You need to use an **assuming** clause to tell Maple that **m** and **n** are integer, and you need to use option **AllSolutions** to **int** to tell it to do a case-by-case analysis of the parameters. For example,

```
int(sin(n*Pi*x/L)*sin(m*Pi*x/L), x= 0..L, AllSolutions) 
     assuming n::posint, m::posint, L>0;
```

I've assumed positivity of all parameters simply to reduce the number of cases presented in Maple's answer.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. You saved me.

(you are right, This is more of a math Question than a programming Question.)